# Why am I getting "debug domain is off" error message when using Xtensa Tensilica OCD?

Tags: debugging, jtag, cadence, xtensa

I'm trying to start Tensilica's Xtensa OCD Daemon by typing xt-ocd.exe in the appropriate directory but I keep getting a warning stating that "Debug domain is OFF (PWRSTAT:0x0)!" followed by an error message saying "Cannot set JTAG Usable bit while debug module is off (PWRSTAT=0x0)!". I have made sure that my external debugger is actually powered. It seems like the "debug domain" (whatever that means!) is off and I don't know how to turn it on. There's virtually no documentation on this.

Has anyone had the same problem or does anyone know how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when the Xtensa processor was in reset mode. Check to ensure that the processor is not in reset.